# Reading avro files in R

Tags: r, avro

Although there is a description of reading these files at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sparkavro/sparkavro.pdf i wanna know if i can read avro file from my local drive using R. The code which is given in pdf file is given below which may need connection with spark. Since i have avro files in local directory i am not sure if i should set default directory as i do with other csv files.

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
df <- spark_read_avro(
  sc,
  "twitter",
  system.file("extdata/twitter.avro", package = "sparkavro"),
  repartition = FALSE,
  memory = FALSE)
```

Comment: These links may be useful to you  https://therinspark.com/data.html  and   https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/07/sparklyr-1-3-higher-order-functions-avro-and-custom-serializers

Comment: unfortunately i just have avro files on my local drive and it doesnt need to be connected to spark at the moment.